# How to connect processes with subsets

Tags: erlang

I want to store different processes in subsets.

S=Subset, P= Process

```
-module(fibo).
-export([main/0,proc/0]).

main() ->
S1 = [] ,S2 = [], S3 = [],
% init each processes with [1,1] = first and second fibo number
P1 = spawn(S1,?MODULE, proc,[1,1]),
P2 = spawn(S2,?MODULE, proc,[1,1]),
P3 = spawn(S3,?MODULE, proc,[1,1]),
P4 = spawn(S3,?MODULE, proc,[1,1]).

proc() ->
    receive
        {S,setGroup, N} ->
        io:format(" ~p - ~p - ~p~n",[S,self(),N]);
        _ ->
            io:format(" failed ~n")
    end.
```

but if i run the `main` function i get this exception/error:

```
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  spawn/4
        called as spawn([],fibo,proc,[1,1])
     in call from fibo:main/0 (fibo.erl, line 36)
```

Why can I not connect P1...P4 with S1..S3?
line 36 = P1 = spawn(S1,?MODULE, proc,[1,1]),

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of spawn/4 is node name. Node is not a set of processes. Also, in Erlang Variables are immutable. Calling spawn cannot modify the empty list. To store process pids, you have to create new list by appending new element.

Comment: okey, can I write something like that, to connect P1 with subset S1? `P1 = spawn(?MODULE, proc,[]), ... S1 = [P1,P2,P3],...P1 ! {[1,1],setGroup, S1}. ... proc() ->receive {N,setGroup, S} -> io:format(" ~p - ~p - ~p~n",[N,self(),S]); _ -> io:format(" failed ~n") end.`

Comment: Yes, but be aware that `N` will get the value `[1,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the first argument to `spawn/4` being a node the last argument to spawn is a **list** of arguments to the function, so writing `spawn(?MODULE,proc,[1,1])` will call `proc/2`, it will make the call `proc(1,1)`. You have defined `proc/0`, a function with no arguments, and in erlang these are different functions.